# getting a value out of show.bs.collapse twitter bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, accordion

I need to be able to get the href value from the accordion item i just clicked on i assumed this would work (its using twitters collapse plug in)

link:

```
<a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" class="accorLink">
```

grab it:

```
$('#accordion').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
    console.log('foo');
    var sectionID = $(this).attr("href");
    console.log(sectionID);
})
```

but its not working and just logging "undefined"

am I able to get a value from it ideally the href

Comment: that's because `this` refers to the `#accordian` div

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason its returning `undefined` is because you're trying to extract an `href` attribute value that doesn't exist because `this` refers to the `#accordian` div.

You can do this by getting the link without the class `collapsed`:

```
$('#accordion').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
    //get the anchor of the accordian that does not has the class "collapsed"
    var openAnchor = $(this).find('a[data-toggle=collapse]:not(.collapsed)');

    //extract the href
    var sectionID = openAnchor.attr('href');
    console.log(sectionID);
});
```

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mffox/LyNCQ/)

Comment: this was what i was after